# Why numpy.resize doesn't work with '-1' like numpy.reshape?

Tags: python, numpy, resize, reshape

I learned that `numpy.reshape` doesn't really change the array's shape. Ok. And I can use `numpy.resize` instead. That's fine.

My question is why the '-1' notation doesn't work using 'np.resize'? As it does with 'np.reshape'...

```
myarray = np.arange(16)

myarray.resize((4,-1))
```

gives me

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-606-aa09b20c947a> in <module>
      1 myarray = np.arange(16)
      2 
----> 3 myarray.resize((4,-1))

ValueError: negative dimensions not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

As I checked, *resize* does not allow negative arguments.
It is a feature of *reshape* (and some other methods, but **not** *resize*).

If you want to have a **new** array, change your code to:

```
myNewArray = myarray.reshape((4,-1)).copy()
```

Another solution to change the shape in-place:

```
myarray.shape = (4, -1)
```

Here you **may** pass *-1* as one element of the new shape tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Since `reshape` (method or function) does not change the total number of elements, it can safely calculate one of dimensions, given the others.

`resize` can change the total number of elements, so it can't safely make any assumptions about the desired dimensions.

Looking at code, both in other `numpy` functions, and SO answers, you'll see that `reshape` is widely used.  The fact that it doesn't operate in-place usually isn't a problem.  It returns a `view` (where possible), so time isn't an issue.

Since `resize` can change the number of elements, it can be more dangerous (but occasionally more useful).  Keep in mind that the function form fills with different values than the method form.

I often create sample arrays with

```
arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```